# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@425e3308: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7536743 at offset 208

Tags: android, parcelable

Does anyone have any idea about it? I did not save anything in HomeActivity.
Sorry I mean I don't save extra state, it's only the framework itself.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor/com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor.ui.HomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@425e3308: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7536743 at offset 208
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@425e3308: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7536743 at offset 208
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2080)
       at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2343)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1703)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2034)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2314)
       at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
       at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:876)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1896)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1494)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1896)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1494)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1896)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:216)
       at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
       at com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor.ui.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:25)
       at com.iproperty.android.apps.irealtor.ui.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:64)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

If the activity contain a fragment that have extra saveState, will it throw error on the HomeActivity?

Comment: Could you maybe show us your code? How are we supposed to find the cause of the error without seeing what you did?

Comment: Even if you don't save anything, the app/OS does that for its own good. Please post relevant code, or you can try debugging by removing codes that you suspect giving error.

Comment: @AndrewT. I am trying to reproduce the error, because it's not happen all the time, for now I only seen it happened when the app pause for quite a time, then it will error.

Comment: Same thing is happening with me also. Its not reproducible but crash reports shows is showing same crash